# Find the strongest received signal strength between transmitter and receiver in RFID technology

Tags: rfid

What I want to do it is measure strongest received signal for detection between receiver and transmitter.
I have read the received signal strength (RSS) from tag-RFID to find the location of the tag. I also have the probability distribution of RSS the signal has to take multiple paths to travel from the transmitter to the receiver.
How can I measure strongest received signal for detection between receiver and transmitter, which methods or algorithm can I use and how?

Comment: The strongest signal is usually (nearly always) up close to the transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

As RFID, particularly UHF RFID, is in general a narrowband technology, you encounter a lot of multipath signals and therefore fading. This will lead to the effect, that if you move your tag only a little bit, the RSS may vary a lot. But I guess that is included in your PD.
Therefore, it is hard to tell where you can find the strongest RSS, but I would say it is half to one wavelength after the reader antenna, with maximum polarization.
Otherwise, you can tell your RFID reader to record all RSS measurements and move the tag around (in an anechoic chamber, not by hand due to effects on the signal).